# EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION

Tags: java, javafx

I wanted to test my Javafx application but I am getting an error I had never seen before and couldnt find anything on the internet as a solution it tellse me something with my Java runtime environment but I couldnt really work with the info I am getting maybe someone here can help me:

```
     A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x00000000645ec059, pid=8032, tid=0x0000000000001d60
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_231-b11) (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.231-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x23c059]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Hasan\git\gruppe-a\hs_err_pid8032.log
Compiled method (c1)   24133    1       3      (method)
 total in heap  [0x00000000023cf650,0x00000000023cf958] = 776
 relocation     [0x00000000023cf770,0x00000000023cf7a0] = 48
 main code      [0x00000000023cf7a0,0x00000000023cf860] = 192
 stub code      [0x00000000023cf860,0x00000000023cf8f0] = 144
 metadata       [0x00000000023cf8f0,0x00000000023cf8f8] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00000000023cf8f8,0x00000000023cf910] = 24
 scopes pcs     [0x00000000023cf910,0x00000000023cf950] = 64
 dependencies   [0x00000000023cf950,0x00000000023cf958] = 8
Compiled method (c1)   24133    1       3      (method)
 total in heap  [0x00000000023cf650,0x00000000023cf958] = 776
 relocation     [0x00000000023cf770,0x00000000023cf7a0] = 48
 main code      [0x00000000023cf7a0,0x00000000023cf860] = 192
 stub code      [0x00000000023cf860,0x00000000023cf8f0] = 144
 metadata       [0x00000000023cf8f0,0x00000000023cf8f8] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00000000023cf8f8,0x00000000023cf910] = 24
 scopes pcs     [0x00000000023cf910,0x00000000023cf950] = 64
 dependencies   [0x00000000023cf950,0x00000000023cf958] = 8
Compiled method (c1)   24133    1       3      (method)
 total in heap  [0x00000000023cf650,0x00000000023cf958] = 776
 relocation     [0x00000000023cf770,0x00000000023cf7a0] = 48
 main code      [0x00000000023cf7a0,0x00000000023cf860] = 192
 stub code      [0x00000000023cf860,0x00000000023cf8f0] = 144
 metadata       [0x00000000023cf8f0,0x00000000023cf8f8] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00000000023cf8f8,0x00000000023cf910] = 24
 scopes pcs     [0x00000000023cf910,0x00000000023cf950] = 64
 dependencies   [0x00000000023cf950,0x00000000023cf958] = 8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: While that is an error thrown by native code, it would be good to show a [mre] of the Java code which threw this error.

Comment: the problem is I dont know which part of the code is doing it because it thappens everywhere in my application the moment I click a button for example. It happened after I pulled from what my friends did. But it does not even give a code error or something

Comment: What could be the cause of this error what I mean is, what will throw that error? what does Illegal instruction mean?

Comment: A collegue has pulled the latest version and he does not get that error so it means its more like a computer problem maybe? or ide?

Comment: As I said, it's an error thrown from native code (e.g. C/C++), possibly from the JVM itself. Do you have the correct version of Java for your operating system (including 32-bit vs 64-bit)? Same with JavaFX?

Comment: There are tools that can open dumps, they should be able to show you where in your code that native code was triggered